# jQuery: Change class or image size when a parent div width is changed

Tags: jquery, class, width

I have a logo image that's in a navigation (nav) element and I want that logo image to change to a smaller size when the nav width is reduced. What would be the best and simple jquery function for this?

```
<nav id="nav">
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn home"><div class="menu-item"><span>01</span> home</a></div> <div class="hr-line"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn about"><div class="menu-item"><span>02</span> about</a></div> <div class="hr-line"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn brands"><div class="menu-item"><span>03</span> brands</a></div> <div class="hr-line"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn contact"><div class="menu-item"><span>04</span> contact</a></div> <div class="hr-line"></div></li>
</ul>
```

So when nav#nav reduces to 60px width, the .logo class will switch to a .logo-small class.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the https://api.jquery.com/resize/ function.
Inside the callback you can use the `.width()` function on the element you want to check, and if needed you can call the `.addClass()` to add the CSS class to the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Adding example to Lorenzo S answer. You can use [`resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function to check nav width change and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to  remove original class and use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add new class to anchor element. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var widthNav = $("nav#nav").width();
    if(widthNav<60){
        $("a.logo").removeClass("logo").addClass("logo-small");
    }else{
        $("a.logo").removeClass("logo-small").addClass("logo");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8q6F/)</kbd>